# Lev 18 - Is it "uncovering nakedness" or is it "having sexual relations with"?

Tags: leviticus, sexuality

In Leviticus 18, from verse 6 then on, there is a big chunk of passages about not "uncovering the nakedness" of relatives...or is it about not "having sexual relations with" them?

[This link](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Leviticus%2018:13) provides various translations:

Answer (score 6):

The Hebrew formulation is:

> עֶרְוַ֥ת אֲחֽוֹת־אִמְּךָ֖ לֹ֣א תְגַלֵּ֑ה כִּֽי־שְׁאֵ֥ר אִמְּךָ֖ הִֽוא׃ ([Lev 18:13, Westminster Leningrad Codex](http://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Lev18:6-18:23))

Literally, the term גילוי עריות means "uncovering nakedness". However, this is just a euphemism for sexual relations.

This can be seen from the following verses ([Lev 18:20-23](http://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Lev18:20-18:23)) and the parallel chapter ([Lev 20:11-21](http://tanach.us/Tanach.xml?Lev20:11-20:21)) which speak more explicitly of sexual relations.

Note, however, that since Hebrew does not have explicit terms for sexual relations, all mentions of such actions use euphemisms of various sorts.